# border-radius for masking child SVG

Tags: css, svg

I have a div with an svg child:

```
<div>
  <svg>...</svg>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get rounded corners using CSS. However, if I set `border-radius` on the div it doesn't mask the SVG. This kinda makes sense, but is there a simple alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this code below:

```
.clip-circle {
  clip-path: circle(50px at center);
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I was aware of the circle option but for some reason when I played with it earlier I didn't realize it could do what I needed.

Comment: So I actually just realize that this isn't exactly what I'm looking for, though it's a decent approximation. Ideally I would be able to round each corner with a separate circle. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, if you change the 50px to 70px it should be work. You can play with the circle pixels

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `border-radius` on the SVG.

```css
svg {
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="400" height="300">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="green"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```